# Why is the preview image better quality than the rendered one?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, denoise

[image]First pic is final render, second pic is what is shown on the compositor, can tell me why the one on the compositor has better quality?

[image]

[image]

This is rendered in Blender 2.9

Comment: You should edit the question and add an image of the render settings. Resolution and samples and denoiser settings

Answer (score 1):

If you notice , you have pluged the output of your denoise node in your viewer , if you want the results to be similar to the viewer node output , then you should also plug that into the composite node , the viewer node is only for preview and compositor makes changes in the render itself